# Record inputs and outputs for every method execution for future testing, and test selection

Tags: testing, profiling, aspectj, instrumentation, chronon

I have actually tried manually implementing this. Calling my own implemented method at the beginning of each method and before each return. Using serialization for storing inputs outputs, also for deep comparison of non-primitive objects. However, the programs that I tried to use this involves many indirect inputs and outputs such as class instance variables, variables from superclass, etc... I handled this by using reflection.

BUT it just became way too time consuming because of all the serialization and deserialization, I do need to access the inputs and outputs besides recording and testing, because I want to do some test selection based on the input values.

Has anyone done that? 
I looked into Chronon, but it is approaching this feature in a very complex way that I had no way to systematically access all the recorded input and output info.

I also tried to look into profiling, aspectj, but I got lost and didn't want to spend too much time reading all kinds of stuff if someone has a better idea about this.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a question fit for being published on SO. There is no code, no concrete problem with that code, only a vague topic which would create opinionated discussion rather than yield a clear or even correct answer. I suggest you delete the question.

Comment: I think suggesting me to provide further details is better than just telling me I asked a stupid question and I should delete my question, nicely done kriegaex. Also I think I have explained my question quiet clearly, and what I am looking to get help is other's opinions on how I can approach my problem differently or if there's a existingtool that fits into the description.

Comment: I did not say at all that the question was stupid. Read again, please. I said it is not fit for SO because this is a Q/A format and not a discussion format. So please keep your blame to yourself. I was just being nice, explaining why you will probably just get close votes or down votes for this one. Besides, I did not down vote it, I only commented. My recommendation is indeed to delete the question because it does not belong here because you cannot provide any code that needs improvement. And as for clarity, to me it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve.